# Trigger validation when the value is changed by program?

Tags: wpf, validation, c#-4.0, datagrid, triggers

Trigger validation when the value is changed by program?

I have a data grid, it has a column 'Status'. When user click a button, it start a background worker doing a long processing based on the data in datagrid rows: loop for the rows, which is an ObservableCollection . For a row, it will report the processing status and show it in the 'Status' column (as a string). Sometimes, the 'Status' will include text like:

Error: ....
Warning: ...

I want to change the Status cell background based on the Status text, i.e. red for Error, gray for Warning ...

Can I do this by using Validation? I coded below. If I manually change the status text, it works like what I wanted. local:StatusValidationRule checks whether it has Error. but, this does not work since the status text is changed by program, which does not trigger the validation.

Any suggestions? thanks.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="200" CanUserResize="True"> 

    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Status" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:StatusValidationRule  ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>

    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap">
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your validator to `<local:StatusValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"`, this should cause it to validate anytime the target property is updated

Comment: thanks, that answered the questions. can you reply it as answer, so I can accept it? thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated` on your `ValidationRule` this will cause it to validate anytime the target property is updated.

Example:

```
<local:StatusValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
```